# Timer which impede its own functions to run unless being in step by step

Tags: vb.net, timer

I have an issue for which I'm stuck with since last week, and this despite of the advises from the senior developer.

I want to send a motorisation command to a motor by the COM ports through a timer.

- When I do it step by step or when I add a stopping point, this is
  okay! However, when I let the timer and the program run by
  themselves, the motorisation command never happens! Why? The command
  should run as far as the step by step method does!

I am actually calling a method `envoi_commande_motorisation()` without any arguments. It just sends frames in the specific format to the COM port in order to make the motor move. Yet it seems never to be called when quitting the debugging step-by-step. This command is contained by `Timer_moto_tick(sender, e) As Timer_moto.tick` which is just the timer I made to regularly verify that the motor is at the right azimut, knowing its position with `Demande_etat_motorisation()`.

I changed the frequency of the timer from 1000ms to 3000ms by a step of 500ms each time but it didn't changed anything...

- I added a button that calls for `envoi_commande_motorisation()`
  manually and it works! Yet, this is by hand and I want to automatize
  it.

Here is a picture of the crime scene:

```
Private Sub Timer_moto_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer_moto.Tick
    'asking for the motor position
    Demande_etat_motorisation()

    'checking if we are acually in the automatize management of the motor and not in the manual way
    If RadioButton_Manuel.Checked = False Then
        'checking if the motor isn't already at the right place
        If ((CDbl(Liste_azimut.Text) <> Val(Aff_position_azimut_source.Text)) Or (CDbl(Liste_elevation.Text) <> Val(Aff_position_site_source.Text))) Then
            'otherwise we change the motor position text and say him to go this way
            lecture_port_comm_moto()
            Liste_azimut.Text = CType(Val(Aff_position_azimut_source.Text), String)
            Liste_elevation.Text = CType(Val(Aff_position_site_source.Text), String)
            envoi_commande_motorisation()

        End If

        envoi_commande_motorisation()

    End If

End Sub
```

As asked in the comments I also gives `Demande_etat_motorisation` and `envoi_commande_motorisation`

```
Public Sub Demande_etat_motorisation()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim info As String

    If init_en_cours = True Then Exit Sub


    'asking for motor state
    'frame in hexa  : 57 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1F 20
    tableau_hexa(0) = &H57
    For i = 1 To 10
        tableau_hexa(i) = &H00
    Next i
    tableau_hexa(11) = &H1F
    tableau_hexa(12) = &H20
    'envoi de la données
    info = "sending frames on ports "
    'port 1 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    If etat_port_4.Checked = True And CheckBox_Moto_1.Checked = True Then
        'chosing which port for motorisation
        Try

            Select Case Liste_port_4.Text
                Case Zone_param_comm1.Text
                    Port_serie_1.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                    Port_serie_1.ReceivedBytesThreshold = seuil_port_reception_moto
                Case Zone_param_comm2.Text
                    Port_serie_2.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                    Port_serie_2.ReceivedBytesThreshold = seuil_port_reception_moto
                Case Zone_param_comm3.Text
                    Port_serie_3.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                    Port_serie_3.ReceivedBytesThreshold = seuil_port_reception_moto

            End Select

        Catch ex As Exception
            zone1.Text = "Error Motorisation 1 : " + ex.ToString
        End Try
    End If
    'End If
    'port 2 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    If etat_port_5.Checked = True And CheckBox_Moto_2.Checked = True Then
        'sending the command
        'here we chose which port to write in for the motor
        Try
            'assignation du à ouvrir
            Select Case Liste_port_5.Text
                Case Zone_param_comm1.Text
                    Port_serie_1.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                    Port_serie_1.ReceivedBytesThreshold = seuil_port_reception_moto
                Case Zone_param_comm2.Text
                    Port_serie_2.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                    Port_serie_2.ReceivedBytesThreshold = seuil_port_reception_moto
                Case Zone_param_comm3.Text
                    Port_serie_3.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                    Port_serie_3.ReceivedBytesThreshold = seuil_port_reception_moto

            End Select

        Catch ex As Exception
            zone1.Text = "Error Motorisation 2 : " + ex.ToString
        End Try
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub envoi_commande_motorisation()
    'sending data on serial ports
    'sending 13 chars
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cjunk, cjunk1 As String
    Dim nombre As Integer
    Dim info As String

    BorneMinAz = Nothing
    BorneMaxAz = Nothing
    BorneMinElev = Nothing
    BorneMaxElev = Nothing

    If init_en_cours = True Then Exit Sub
    If Me.Liste_azimut.Text <> "" And Me.Liste_elevation.Text <> "" Then
        Me.zone1.Text = ""
        'classical command is being sent
        tableau_hexa(0) = &H57
        tableau_hexa(1) = &H30
        'in degree degre
        tableau_hexa(5) = &H1
        tableau_hexa(6) = &H30

        tableau_hexa(10) = &H1
        'final bits for a command
        tableau_hexa(11) = &H2F
        tableau_hexa(12) = &H20
        'azimut calculation
        nombre = CInt(Liste_azimut.Text) + 360
        cjunk1 = CStr(nombre)

        'numbers upper to 100
        cjunk = Mid(cjunk1, 1, 1)
        tableau_hexa(2) = CByte(&H30 + Val(cjunk))
        'having back the decade
        cjunk = Mid(cjunk1, 2, 1)
        tableau_hexa(3) = CByte(&H30 + Val(cjunk))
        'unite
        cjunk = Mid(cjunk1, 3, 1)
        tableau_hexa(4) = CByte(&H30 + Val(cjunk))

        'tilt calculation
        nombre = CInt(Liste_elevation.Text) + 360
        cjunk1 = CStr(nombre)

        'number upper to 100
        cjunk = Mid(cjunk1, 1, 1)
        tableau_hexa(7) = CByte(&H30 + Val(cjunk))
        'decade recuperation
        cjunk = Mid(cjunk1, 2, 1)
        tableau_hexa(8) = CByte(&H30 + Val(cjunk))
        'unite
        cjunk = Mid(cjunk1, 3, 1)
        tableau_hexa(9) = CByte(&H30 + Val(cjunk))
        'affichage de la trame envoyée
        cjunk = ""
        For i = 0 To 12
            cjunk = cjunk + CStr(Hex(tableau_hexa(i))) + " "
        Next
        envoi_azimut_elevation.Text = "frame sent: " + cjunk


        info = "frames being sent on the port : "
        'port 1

        'motorisation 1 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        If etat_port_4.Checked = True And CheckBox_Moto_1.Checked = True Then
            'chosing port for motor 1
            Try

                Select Case Liste_port_4.Text
                    Case Zone_param_comm1.Text
                        Port_serie_1.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                        Port_serie_1.ReceivedBytesThreshold = seuil_port_reception_moto
                    Case Zone_param_comm2.Text
                        Port_serie_2.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                        Port_serie_2.ReceivedBytesThreshold = seuil_port_reception_moto
                    Case Zone_param_comm3.Text
                        Port_serie_3.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                        Port_serie_3.ReceivedBytesThreshold = seuil_port_reception_moto

                End Select

            Catch ex As Exception
                zone1.Text = "Erreur Motorisation 1 : " + ex.ToString
            End Try

            'affichage de l'info sur l'afficheur noir
            'azimut
            i = CInt(Val(Liste_azimut.Text))
            Select Case i
                Case 0 To 9
                    Affiche_info_azimut.Text = "00" + Format(i, "##0")
                Case 10 To 99
                    Affiche_info_azimut.Text = "0" + Format(i, "##0")
                Case Else
                    Affiche_info_azimut.Text = Format(i, "##0")
            End Select
            Affiche_info_azimut.ForeColor = Color.Green
            'tilt
            i = CInt(Val(Liste_elevation.Text))
            Select Case i
                Case -9 To -1
                    Affiche_info_elevation.Text = "-0" + Format(Abs(i), "##")
                Case 0 To 9
                    Affiche_info_elevation.Text = "0" + Format(i, "##")

                Case Else
                    Affiche_info_elevation.Text = Format(i, "##")
            End Select
            Affiche_info_elevation.ForeColor = Color.Green


        End If
        'port 2 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        If etat_port_5.Checked = True And CheckBox_Moto_2.Checked = True Then
            'envoi de la commande
            'choix du port choisi pour la motorisation 1
            Try
                'assignation du à ouvrir
                Select Case Liste_port_5.Text
                    Case Zone_param_comm1.Text
                        Port_serie_1.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                        Port_serie_1.ReceivedBytesThreshold = seuil_port_reception_moto
                    Case Zone_param_comm2.Text
                        Port_serie_2.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                        Port_serie_2.ReceivedBytesThreshold = seuil_port_reception_moto
                    Case Zone_param_comm3.Text
                        Port_serie_3.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                        Port_serie_3.ReceivedBytesThreshold = seuil_port_reception_moto

                End Select

            Catch ex As Exception
                zone1.Text = "Erreur Motorisation 2 : " + ex.ToString
            End Try
            'affichage de l'info sur l'afficheur noir
            'azimut
            i = CInt(Val(Liste_azimut.Text))
            Select Case i
                Case 0 To 9
                    Affiche_info_azimut.Text = "00" + Format(i, "##0")
                Case 10 To 99
                    Affiche_info_azimut.Text = "0" + Format(i, "##0")
                Case Else
                    Affiche_info_azimut.Text = Format(i, "##0")
            End Select
            Affiche_info_azimut.ForeColor = Color.LightGreen
            'elevation
            i = CInt(Val(Liste_elevation.Text))
            Select Case i
                Case -9 To -1
                    Affiche_info_elevation.Text = "-0" + Format(Abs(i), "##")
                Case 0 To 9
                    Affiche_info_elevation.Text = "0" + Format(i, "##")

                Case Else
                    Affiche_info_elevation.Text = Format(i, "##")
            End Select

            Affiche_info_elevation.ForeColor = Color.Green

            'demande de position
            Demande_etat_motorisation()

        End If
        'End If
        '
    End If

End Sub
```

Hitherto, the senior developer still believes it is a timer frequency issue.

Maybe should I work with interruptions for the serial ports, but how can I actually do this? He told me to set the threshold for each ports in order to start reading by interruption, so that I read the buffer when it is full.

**Edit:**

#### Diagnostics.Debug.Writeline

As advised, I wrote `Diagnostics.Debug.Writeline("some specific text here")` everywhere my program may have crashed. Actually, after picking up on the lines written in the terminal,  I noticed that it is the `Serialports.Writeline(,,)` that creates problems.

Indeed whith the following code and debug lines:

```
Private Sub Timer_moto_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer_moto.Tick
    'asking for the motor position
    Demande_etat_motorisation()

    'checking if we are acually in the automatize management of the motor and not in the manual way
    If RadioButton_Manuel.Checked = False Then

        Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("test if we are at the right place")

        If ((CDbl(Liste_azimut.Text) <> Val(Aff_position_azimut_source.Text)) Or (CDbl(Liste_elevation.Text) <> Val(Aff_position_site_source.Text))) Then
            lecture_port_comm_moto()
            Liste_azimut.Text = CType(Val(Aff_position_azimut_source.Text), String)
            Liste_elevation.Text = CType(Val(Aff_position_site_source.Text), String)
            envoi_commande_motorisation()

            Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("we have just send the orders to the camera")

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Every debug lines being read on the terminal, I added some in `envoi_commande_motorisation()`

```
Public Sub envoi_commande_motorisation()
'sending data on serial ports
'sending 13 chars
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cjunk, cjunk1 As String
    Dim nombre As Integer
    Dim info As String

    BorneMinAz = Nothing
    BorneMaxAz = Nothing
    BorneMinElev = Nothing
    BorneMaxElev = Nothing

    Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("We just get into envoi_commande_motorisation()")

    If init_en_cours = True Then Exit Sub
    If Me.Liste_azimut.Text <> "" And Me.Liste_elevation.Text <> "" Then
        Me.zone1.Text = ""
    'classical command is being sent
        tableau_hexa(0) = &H57
        tableau_hexa(1) = &H30
        'transforming it in degree
        tableau_hexa(5) = &H1
        tableau_hexa(6) = &H30
        'again
        tableau_hexa(10) = &H1
        'final bits for a command

        tableau_hexa(11) = &H2F
        tableau_hexa(12) = &H20
        'azimut calculation
        nombre = CInt(Liste_azimut.Text) + 360
        cjunk1 = CStr(nombre)

        'number bigger than 100
        cjunk = Mid(cjunk1, 1, 1)
        tableau_hexa(2) = CByte(&H30 + Val(cjunk))
        'taking the decade
        cjunk = Mid(cjunk1, 2, 1)
        tableau_hexa(3) = CByte(&H30 + Val(cjunk))
        'unity
        cjunk = Mid(cjunk1, 3, 1)
        tableau_hexa(4) = CByte(&H30 + Val(cjunk))

        'elevation calculation
        nombre = CInt(Liste_elevation.Text) + 360
        cjunk1 = CStr(nombre)

        'number bigger than 100
        cjunk = Mid(cjunk1, 1, 1)
        tableau_hexa(7) = CByte(&H30 + Val(cjunk))
        'taking the decade
        cjunk = Mid(cjunk1, 2, 1)
        tableau_hexa(8) = CByte(&H30 + Val(cjunk))
        'units
        cjunk = Mid(cjunk1, 3, 1)
        tableau_hexa(9) = CByte(&H30 + Val(cjunk))
        displaying the frame sent 
        cjunk = ""
        For i = 0 To 12
            cjunk = cjunk + CStr(Hex(tableau_hexa(i))) + " "
        Next
        envoi_azimut_elevation.Text = "Trame envoi : " + cjunk


        Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("We are going to get into the writes")


        info = "sending data on ports "
        'port 1
        'motorisation 1 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        If etat_port_4.Checked = True And CheckBox_Moto_1.Checked = True Then
            'chosing ports
            Try

                Select Case Liste_port_4.Text
                    Case Zone_param_comm1.Text
                        Port_serie_1.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                    'Port_serie_1.ReceivedBytesThreshold = seuil_port_reception_moto
                    Case Zone_param_comm2.Text
                        Port_serie_2.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                    'Port_serie_2.ReceivedBytesThreshold = seuil_port_reception_moto
                    Case Zone_param_comm3.Text
                        Port_serie_3.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                    'Port_serie_3.ReceivedBytesThreshold = seuil_port_reception_moto
                    Case Zone_param_comm4.Text
                        Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("we are going to write in COM port 4")

                        Port_serie_4.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                        Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("We just wrote in COM Port 4")
                        Timer_moto.Start()
                    'Port_serie_4.ReceivedBytesThreshold = seuil_port_reception_moto
                    Case Zone_param_comm5.Text
                        Port_serie_5.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                    'Port_serie_5.ReceivedBytesThreshold = seuil_port_reception_moto
                    Case Zone_param_comm6.Text
                        Port_serie_6.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                        'Port_serie_6.ReceivedBytesThreshold = seuil_port_reception_moto
                End Select

            Catch ex As Exception
                zone1.Text = "Erreur Motorisation 1 : " + ex.ToString
            End Try

            'displaying azimut infomations on screen
            'azimut
            i = CInt(Val(Liste_azimut.Text))
            Select Case i
                Case 0 To 9
                    Affiche_info_azimut.Text = "00" + Format(i, "##0")
                Case 10 To 99
                    Affiche_info_azimut.Text = "0" + Format(i, "##0")
                Case Else
                    Affiche_info_azimut.Text = Format(i, "##0")
            End Select
            Affiche_info_azimut.ForeColor = Color.Green
            'elevation
            i = CInt(Val(Liste_elevation.Text))
            Select Case i
                Case -9 To -1
                    Affiche_info_elevation.Text = "-0" + Format(Abs(i), "##")
                Case 0 To 9
                    Affiche_info_elevation.Text = "0" + Format(i, "##")

                Case Else
                    Affiche_info_elevation.Text = Format(i, "##")
            End Select
            Affiche_info_elevation.ForeColor = Color.Green


        End If
        'port 2 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        If etat_port_5.Checked = True And CheckBox_Moto_2.Checked = True Then
            'sending command
            'chosing port
            Try

                Select Case Liste_port_5.Text
                    Case Zone_param_comm1.Text
                        Port_serie_1.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                    'Port_serie_1.ReceivedBytesThreshold = seuil_port_reception_moto
                    Case Zone_param_comm2.Text
                        Port_serie_2.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                    'Port_serie_2.ReceivedBytesThreshold = seuil_port_reception_moto
                    Case Zone_param_comm3.Text
                        Port_serie_3.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                    'Port_serie_3.ReceivedBytesThreshold = seuil_port_reception_moto
                    Case Zone_param_comm4.Text
                        Port_serie_4.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                    'Port_serie_4.ReceivedBytesThreshold = seuil_port_reception_moto
                    Case Zone_param_comm5.Text
                        Port_serie_5.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                    'Port_serie_5.ReceivedBytesThreshold = seuil_port_reception_moto
                    Case Zone_param_comm6.Text
                        Port_serie_6.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                        'Port_serie_6.ReceivedBytesThreshold = seuil_port_reception_moto
                End Select

            Catch ex As Exception
                zone1.Text = "Erreur Motorisation 2 : " + ex.ToString
            End Try
            'affichage de l'info sur l'afficheur noir
            'azimut
            i = CInt(Val(Liste_azimut.Text))
            Select Case i
                Case 0 To 9
                    Affiche_info_azimut.Text = "00" + Format(i, "##0")
                Case 10 To 99
                    Affiche_info_azimut.Text = "0" + Format(i, "##0")
                Case Else
                    Affiche_info_azimut.Text = Format(i, "##0")
            End Select
            Affiche_info_azimut.ForeColor = Color.LightGreen
            'elevation
            i = CInt(Val(Liste_elevation.Text))
            Select Case i
                Case -9 To -1
                    Affiche_info_elevation.Text = "-0" + Format(Abs(i), "##")
                Case 0 To 9
                    Affiche_info_elevation.Text = "0" + Format(i, "##")

                Case Else
                    Affiche_info_elevation.Text = Format(i, "##")
            End Select

            Affiche_info_elevation.ForeColor = Color.Green

            'demande de position
            'Demande_etat_motorisation()

        End If
        'End If
        '
    End If
End Sub
```

**Every `Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` messages are read and displayed on the terminal but the camera doesn't move**. Therefore, when linked to COM port 4, I think it is `Port_serie_4.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)` that has a serious issue,
 even when the rest of the code is delayed as shown after.
An odd thing is that it always write me `test if we are at the right place` then. Even if I give it orders to move, like if he thought we were at the right place unless clicking on the button that calls for `envoi_commande_motorisation()`.
.

#### delay

I added a delay too just here:

```
               Case Zone_param_comm4.Text
                    Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("we are going to write in COM port 4")

                    Port_serie_4.Write(tableau_hexa, 0, 13)
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                    Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("We just wrote in COM Port 4")
```

Yet, nothing change for the moment.

---

Maybe I should delete some parts of the code of this question or from above. Feel free to suggest it and thanks for all the help you are all bringing for coping with this issue.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem weeks ago, never found the solution... Good luck!

Comment: Can you show what that method does? Also `send a motorisation command to a motorisation` can you explain this. I look at your code and it looks like you are just calling a method and not passing anything to it?

Comment: You might want to log to a file. Log all the values of your variables.

Comment: Please add the code directly to your question as text instead of as a picture.  Also, enable Option Strict for your project; Project Menu->Proj Name Properties->Compile Table-Option Strict = On and fix all the issues the IDE identifies.  The code is comparing numeric types to string types; this requires an implicit conversion and is hard to predict what is being compared.  For example `Liste_azimute.Text <> Val(Aff_position_azimute_source.Text`;  this is trying to compare a `String` to a `Double`.

Comment: `I edited my question describing what are the main functions doing` thank you, but this is not going to help us as we can't ***see what it is doing***... It is more than likely something in that method (timing/code execution issue).

Comment: @Zaggler I commented the code, is it better or are you talking about `envoi_commande_motorisation()`? It only sends frames through a COM port.
**timing**: I tried it from 1000ms to 3000ms, with steps of 500ms but no change, `envoi_commande_motorisation()` is only called during step-by step
**code execution issue**: only the step by step or given stop points reach `envoi_commande_motorisation()`.

Comment: The problem is not likely in the Timer, but that "logic" preceding the call.  Some simple `Console.WriteLine()` statements should help determine why it doesnt seem to call the method when not stepping.  Check that the motor/thing doesnt just quit reposing after getting a certain number of invalid commands.  And **do** turn on `Option Strict`!

Comment: @Plutonix I turned option strict on and I am correcting the errors which are, for the moment, dates that don't have to become String unless using `toString` and things like that... I added a button that calls for `envoi_commande_motorisation()` manually and it works! Yet, this is by hand and I want to automatize it. Thanks for the tips `Console.WriteLine()`, but how does it work?

Comment: `I added a button that calls for envoi_commande_motorisation() manually and it works`, press the button really quick a few times and what happens?

Comment: @Zaggler The first click moves the motor, the next ones don't change anything.

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect the changes you made.  Also include the code for the `Demande_etat_motorisation` and `envoi_commande_motorisation` methods

Comment: `The first click moves the motor, the next ones don't change anything.`  Is this because the various `Text` properties used in the calculations are same for each button press?  If so, write the code to change those values on each click.

Comment: @TnTinMn No, I rather think that it is because the order to move the motor to the specific location is given, this change the text displayed for the azimut, for instance, and imply that there are no more move to do when doing `envoi_commande_motorisation()` again.

Comment: Where is the code that starts the timer? Does it ever get executed?

Comment: Maybe it will help you understand what happens, could you add `Debug.Writeline("Some text here")` at some points in your code. That way the Visual Studio console will display message when the code runs by. This is really helpfull, as you will know without step-by-step debugging where your code goes by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have tried to do a bit too much at a time here. Maybe you need to start by writing a very simple program that actually works, then build on it.

First of all, create a new project with a form and a button. When you click the button, it opens the COM port.

If that works, you just send one command after opening your port. a command that will set your camera at a given position.

If that works, you add a TextBox where you can enter the wanted position. So when you click the button, it will move the camera to that position.

If that works, ...

And you keep building up like this, until you find what was going wrong

Comment: This is what I'm doing right now, with the tiny new one I am able to move the motor by myself and read the camera position. I am looking forward to make the camera conduct the motor

Comment: @JaurèsUlm OK then, when you finally run into something that is not working, please post the code that was working and the modification you added. That way the problem is narrowed and maybe some idea will pop up on why it's not working...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have not disabled some interrupts during your debugging, there is something that is asynchronously able to complete during the delay of you hitting 'next' when you single step through the programs that does not complete when you let it run automatically.  I looked through your code and nothing is obvious.

First try adding a delay between the steps you make with the debugger.  Something like one second per step, so it will be like you are hitting 'next...next...next' but instead it will just be 'delay...delay...delay'  If that works, try eliminating the delays one at a time until it stops working.  Then you will know which part of your code is looking for results that are not yet ready.

I suspect you need something in your code that will check to see the previous communication is complete.  Then if the previous comm is not complete you will do nothing until the next cycle.  You will probably be best off to turn your code into a state machine where you walk through the operations one at a time and do not move to the next state until you can verify the system is done with the previous state.

Comment: That's a good idea! I just tried and wrote about it in the end of the question. I am afraid about delaying the same thread. Do I need to run my work on a separate thread?
Yet, I think it crashes on `Serialports.Writeline(,,) `.
I do need to turn my code not to move to the next state until you I can verify the system is done. But hoiw to do it?

Comment: Does your serial port controller give any sort of feedback about what state it is in: waiting, moving, error, etc?  If it is a truly open loop controller then you are just going to have to take a tic counter snapshot and not do anything else until the tic counter has reached a certain number of microseconds after which you know the controller will be done with the previous command.

Comment: As for 'delaying' the thread, I would not add a literal delay but rather use the tic counter to decide when enough time has passed.  `state_1: start_tic = tic_count; state = state_2; state_2: if( tic_count > start_tic + DELAY) state = state_3;`

Comment: Fine and thanks! I will try to use this tic counter tomorrow and let you know!